# TranslateY css effect on window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to implement a nice scroll effect for the posts and pages title of my wordpress custom theme. You can see the effect in action [here](https://designmodo.com/wpdb-object-wordpress/). Can someone guide me with the implementation? I've inspected the code, it will rely on the `window.scroll` function and on some css rules like translate and scale. 
Here is the snippet I've extracted from the minified version of the js file.

```
e(window).on("scroll ready load resize resizeEnd", function(o) {
            if (!window.isMobile) {
                var i = e(window).scrollTop()
                  , a = i / 2
                  , r = i / 3
                  , n = i / window.headerHeight
                  , s = 1 - .1 * n
                  , l = 1 - n
                  , d = (i - window.articleOffsetTop) / (window.articleHeight - window.windowHeight / 6);
                i < window.headerHeight ? (e("section.header .title-container").css({
                    "-webkit-transform": "translateY(" + a + "px) scale(" + s + ")",
                    transform: "translateY(" + a + "px) scale(" + s + ")",
                    opacity: l
                }),
```

I'm not a designer so I'm not very confortable with css effects or similar. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This code style is scary - minifiers will put comas for you, don't do multi-line assigments by yourself, code readability drops by 100%. Don't do this: `on("scroll ready load resize resizeEnd` instead put it into separate function like function effect() and run this function inside separate events `.on('scroll', effect(o))` ... Also use normal names, clear code is more imporant in developement phase than performance.

Comment: @Zydnar as I mentioned, the code is taken from the js source of a minified file of the site that use the effect, I didn't modified it, it's only a copy from the original

Comment: If you have license for it - why not. But now it seems like you're asking to modify working code (it works on other website) what would be off topic. *Modify your question, so you will ask where exactly is your problem.* StackOverflow does not do job for you.

Comment: @Zydnar I don't want to modify the original code, I don't know if you have seen the link and the header with the effect, I just asking for a suggestion on how to achieve the same effect, the code is an example!

Comment: Use debugging - inspect element before effect and copy it's CSS properties and save it as class `.init` than do the same for state after effect and save properties as class `.after` add for changed element `animation: 1s all ease-in` and simply switch between two classes. It's just one of many possible solutions. Of course put everything inside `$(window).on('scroll`,...`

Comment: I need to try, I was debugging the js code, but nor css. I will take a look also to the css and then try it on jsfoddle. It will apply the effect on the main section container and on the inner elements, but as I wrote, I need to inspect css first to be sure

Comment: @Zydnar I've debugged the css code, the translate, scale and opacity css properties are applied on scroll start. these rules are present on two elements inside the main header that seems to be only a container with no effect. I've noted the initial values and the values when the scroll end and the section will be offscreen. I think now that the trick is with the calculations made in the js snippet.